# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "realm-secret" : secrets "realm-secret" not found

Tags: kubernetes, keycloak

I am trying to get keycloak up and running on my minikube.

I am installing keycloak with

`helm upgrade -i -f kubernetes/keycloak/values.yaml keycloak stable/keycloak --set keycloak.persistence.dbHost=rolling-newt-postgresql`

I see an error in dashboard that says:

> MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "realm-secret" : secrets
>   "realm-secret" not found

In my `values.yaml` I have this configuration:

```
  extraVolumes: |
    - name: realm-secret
      secret:
        secretName: realm-secret
    - name: theme
      emptyDir: {}
    - name: spi
      emptyDir: {}
  extraVolumeMounts: |
    - name: realm-secret
      mountPath: "/realm/"
      readOnly: true
    - name: theme
      mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/themes/mytheme
    - name: spi
      mountPath: /opt/jboss/keycloak/standalone/deployments
```

I also have a `realm.json` file.

**Question**

What do I need to do with this `real.json` file prior to installing keycloak? How do I do that ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason is you are referencing a secret named `realm-secret` in `extraVolumes`, but that secret with name `realm-secret` is created neither by the helm chart (named `stable/keycloak`) nor by you manually.

You can easily find that chart in https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/keycloak.

#### Solution

In `values.yaml`, the field `extraVolume` and `extraVolumeMount` is kept to provide an extra `volume` and extra `volumeMount` by user if they need. They will be used in the keycloak pod.

So if you need to provide `extraVolumes` that will mount a secret, then you have to create that secret all by yourself, so you'll need to create secret `realm-secret` in the same namespace in which you install/upgrade your chart. And only then install/upgrade the chart.

```
$ kubectl create secret generic realm-secret --namespace=<chart_namespace> --from-file=path/to/realm.json
```